# Why do we say “Il se sent mieux” and not “Il sent mieux”?

Tags: grammaire

Please explain it to me like I’m 5, I’m very new to French.

Comment: You might also compare the very different *il se sent meilleur* and *il sent meilleur*...

Comment: Est-ce que ton chat se sent bien dans la boîte?

Answer (score 7):

In *Il sent mieux* we have the verb *sentir*. This verb means "to smell".
So if you say *Il sent mieux maintenant qu'il n'est plus enrhumé* it means "he smells better  now that his cold is over", which in better English would be:  "he can smell better now that his cold is over".

In  *Il se sent mieux* we have the verb *se sentir* which is a [reflexive verb](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/reflexive-verbs) (it has *se*) and *se sentir* means "to feel".
So if you say *il se sent mieux maintenant qu'il a bien dormi* it means: "he feels better now that he's had a good sleep".

Comment: His sense of smell is better now. He smells better, is very ambiguous. As if he stank before....

Comment: @Lambie That's why I wrote  "he can smell better" as "better English". I don't think with "he can smell" there's any ambiguity as to him not stinking so bad.  Not that I would say it myself in such a case but I tried keep  simple for a 5 year old (who might not be fluent at English either).

Comment: If a child is not fluent, all the more reason to say it properly.

Comment: @Lambie None translation is right. You are missing that *Il sent mieux maintenant* is very unidiomatic. Nobody would say it that way. It is so unexpected that it might too be understood to imply he stank before.

Comment: @Lambie "His sense of smell is better now" : *Son odorat s'est amélioré maintenant.*

Comment: @jlliagre Le fait que odorat veut dire sense of smell ne change pas la chose.

Comment: @Lambie "His sense of smell is better now" n'est pas ambigu. "Son odorat s'est amélioré maintenant" n'est pas ambigu. "*He smells better*" est ambigu. "Il sent mieux" est ambigu. Ne vaut-il pas mieux traduire une phrase ambiguë ou un jeu de mot par une autre phrase ambiguë ou un autre jeu de mot, même s'ils ne sont pas à 100 % équivalents ?

Comment: @jlliagre Pour me le dire à moi? Il faut le dire à None.

Answer (score 0):

The verb you are using is a pronominal verb, which means that it has to be conjugated with a reflexive pronoun in the same person.

- Je **me** sen**s** (mieux, bien, mal, à l'aise, faible, …)
  tu **te** sen**s**
  il **se** sen**t**
  nous **nous** sen**tons**
  vous **vous** sen**tez**
  ils **se** sen**tent**

You are dealing with one meaning, the plain meaning of "sentir" when you do not use the pronoun; basically that meaning is that of "to smell"; when you use the pronoun, the meaning changes, and is "to feel".

Although the main part of the verb, that is, the conjugated part is the same, you can say that you are dealing with two different verbs. You can verify that in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sentir).

> III. − Emploi pronominal
> A. − [Le suj. désigne un être vivant doué de sensibilité]
> 1 Empl. pronom. réfl. dir.
> b) **Avoir conscience de l'état physique ou moral dans lequel on se trouve**.
> − [Suivi d'un adj. attribut] Se sentir complexé, coupable, fier, fiévreux, gai, heureux, impuissant, joyeux, libre, moite, triste; se sentir capable de.